# git svn clone fails with "Failed to strip path"

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using git in a shop that is all Subversion.  When I check out a repo using

`git svn clone -s --preserve-empty-dirs https://<subversion-server>/svn/<repo> <folder-name>`

All seems well as the cloning process begins, but at some point during the process, git fails with

`Failed to strip path '<path-to-some-file>' ((?^:^trunk(/|$)))`

Anyone know what's wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: I found that re-running the `git svn clone` command seems to be a valid workaround when using git 2.7.3. It seems that git will continue just where it left off, similarly on network connection failures during `git svn clone`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Searching the interwebs turned up both [an explanation and advice on how to fix this](https://www.semitwist.com/articles/article/view/the-better-svn-git-guide) (see step 4).

But the advice may be dated, as it did not work for my installation (git 2.7.0).  But now knowing the issue, I was able to find the offending line and apply the suggested fix:

The fix was made by changing the offending line in `usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/Git/SVN/Fetcher.pm`, line 163:

Change `die "Failed to strip path...` to `print "Failed to strip path...` and all will be well.

I hope that helps someone else out there as well.

Comment: Performed the change from die to print. Ran this w/o option --no-metadata and was successful.  Also ran the git svn process (with --no-metadata) and it continued to produce a remote repository.  However the clone command output "done" and this, "warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout." I was not able to locate a commit or any data in that clone. The underlying problem is not really explained. I recommend to restore the original 'die' command. When automating and running multiple conversions this could mask a problem that may only manifest when Murphy's Law applies.

Comment: that worked for me in a _jenkins_ container at path `/usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Fetcher.pm`